visual studio code run and debug not working
Began using this with Python a few days ago and love it, but today, the run and debug command doesn't work. Normally, calling the command runs the program in the terminal tab in the bottom part of the window, but today nothing happens.
The terminal still works and I can run the program by calling it there, but there is no communication between the program file in the upper part and the terminal in the lower one.
The automatic Python configs are Node.js (which is "contributed") and Python debugger which is grayed out so I cannot choose it (even though it's installed). It also suggests creating a launch.json file but I have no idea how to do this or why.

This is not a general python question; it is specifically about the Visual Studio IDE.  You will probably get better answers if you add that tag to the question.

What did you change? Yes, that may seem like a silly question, but things don't start behaving differently overnight. Did you try reproducing the issue in a separate workspace?

@ulrich: absolutely. I must have accidentally toggled something. Just can't remember what. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Virtual Studio Code, but that didn't do anything. Incidentally, I'm on a Mac, and I don't see an option to create a launch.json file. Tried to include an image to illustrate, but control + G doesn't work for me.
